# Why do NSDate instances from NSCalendar and NSDateFormatter have slightly different values?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When passing dates over the wire from client to server and back again, I format the date to a string for JSON using the format `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` with the `@"en_US_POSIX"` locale. The same formatter provides an instance of `NSDate` from the date strings returned from the server to the client.

To test the conversions, I am trying to use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` to generate an independent date to use to validate the date from the formatter. However, the `NSDate` instances created from the `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` vary ever so slightly from the `NSDate` instances provided by the `NSDateFormatter`. I do not understand why. Different dates produce a different number of variances. I apologize for yet another `NSDate`/`NSDateFormatter` question, but hope you find it somewhat novel.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
dateFormatter.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSMutableArray *valuesWithError = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:750];
NSMutableArray *valuesThatMatch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:250];

for (NSInteger milliseconds = 0; milliseconds < 1000; milliseconds++) {
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2001-01-01T00:00:00.%03dZ", milliseconds];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    calendar.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

    NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dc.year = 2001;
    dc.month = 1;
    dc.day = 1;
    dc.hour = 0;
    dc.minute = 0;
    dc.second = 0;

    NSDate *expectedDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dc];

    NSTimeInterval baseInterval = [expectedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    double mulitplier = 0.001;
    NSTimeInterval millisecondsToAdd = milliseconds * mulitplier;
    baseInterval += millisecondsToAdd;

    expectedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:baseInterval];

    NSDate *dateFromFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSTimeInterval expectedDateFromReferenceDate = [expectedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval dateFromFormatFromReferenceDate = [dateFromFormat timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    NSTimeInterval differenceByTimeIntervalSubtraction = ABS(expectedDateFromReferenceDate - dateFromFormatFromReferenceDate);

    NSTimeInterval differenceByTimeIntervalFromDate = [expectedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateFromFormat];

    if (![expectedDate isEqualToDate:dateFromFormat]) {
        NSLog(@"Difference = %e", differenceByTimeIntervalSubtraction);
        [valuesWithError addObject:@(milliseconds)];
    } else {
        [valuesThatMatch addObject:@(milliseconds)];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described the variances that you are seeing.

Comment: @rmaddy, The variances are very small (i.e. 9.536743e-10 (min) and 5.912781e-08 (max) for the date above), but they differ depending on the base date and millisecond.

Comment: If the differences are smaller than 0.001 seconds, then what’s the problem? (i.e. if you’re formatting the time as a string with three digits to the right of the decimal, why would you expect values smaller than that to be preserved?)

Comment: @clarkcox3, I think you misunderstand. I don't need the value preserved and might be able to test the date in different ways. I would, however, like to know why the difference is occurring in the first place. I believe understanding the reason will allow me to implement a work around with confidence. Regardless, I'm inclined to think both methods should "hydrate" a date with the same NSTimeInterval.

Comment: This is classic floating point error. You can't represent 99% of the thousandths from 0 through 999/1000 exactly as binary fractions. Therefore `NSTimeInterval millisecondsToAdd = milliseconds * mulitplier;` is giving an inexact result, and the date that you create from there is likewise inexact.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I'm sure the issue lies within the floating point math, but shouldn't the calculation of the approximate fraction be the same on the same computer if calculated two different times?

Comment: @seanwoodward No, I do understand, however it is impossible to exactly represent the value “0.001” as a floating point value. That is the source of the differences that you see. Asking for exact equality between what are essentially floating point types (under the hood NSDate is just a wrapper around NSTimeInterval) is almost always the wrong thing to do. When comparing floating point values, you should instead check that they are within a tolerance that makes sense to you (likely 1ms in your case).

Comment: @clarkcox3, would you argue then, it is never/rarely appropriate to use `[NSDate isEqualTo:somedate]` if sub-second precision is required? Is it possible to us NSDecimalNumber in a way that replicates the precision of '[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:somestring]`?

Comment: @seanwoodward: You're right, and they are; the errors are always the same from run to run. It seems that the `NSDateFormatter` is somehow calculating the milliseconds differently than you are.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, any idea how NSDateFormatter is handling the rounding?

Comment: Yes, I would argue that -[NSDate isEqual:] is almost never appropriate. In the same way as using -[NSNumber isEqual:] is almost never appropriate for floating point values that cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: I believe, based on CoreFoundation, that `NSDateFormatter` uses the ICU library: http://opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-461.12/icuSources/i18n/datefmt.cpp to do the actual work.